# Web browser find anchor and autoclick in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating one tool in which i have used C# browser control, which automatically logs in IRCTC and book the ticket. everything is working fine, except one page. i am not able to click through browser, how can i find the anchor and click through C# browser.Below is the HTML:

```
<table class="rf-dt width100" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns">
            <colgroup span="16">
            </colgroup>
            <thead class="rf-dt-thd" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:th">
                <tr class="rf-dt-shdr" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:ch">
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt261" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        Train No.
                        <div id="up" style="float: right; display: none;">
                        </div>
                        <div id="down" style="float: right; display: none;">
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt265" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        Train Name
                    </th>
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt268" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        From
                    </th>
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt271" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        Departure
                        <div id="up" style="float: right; display: block;" class="up-hdr">
                        </div>
                        <div id="down" style="float: right; display: none;">
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt275" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        To
                    </th>
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt278" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        Arrival
                        <div id="up" style="float: right; display: none;">
                        </div>
                        <div id="down" style="float: right; display: none;">
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt282" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        Dist.(Km)
                        <div id="up" style="float: right; display: none;">
                        </div>
                        <div id="down" style="float: right; display: none;">
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt286" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        Travel Time
                        <div id="up" style="float: right; display: none;">
                        </div>
                        <div id="down" style="float: right; display: none;">
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt290" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        M
                    </th>
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt293" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        T
                    </th>
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt296" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        W
                    </th>
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt299" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        T
                    </th>
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt302" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        F
                    </th>
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt305" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        S
                    </th>
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt308" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        S
                    </th>
                    <th id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:j_idt311" scope="col" class="rf-dt-shdr-c">
                        Class
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="rf-dt-b" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:tb">
                <tr class="rf-dt-r" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:9">
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:9:j_idt261">
                        <a onclick="trainScheFunc('12141','CSTM','Thu Jul 03 00:00:00 IST 2014')" href="#">12141</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt265">
                        RAJENDRA NGR EXP
                    </td>
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt268">
                        CSTM
                    </td>
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt271">
                        23:25
                    </td>
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt275">
                        JBP
                    </td>
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt278">
                        14:15
                    </td>
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt282">
                        997
                    </td>
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt286">
                        14:50
                    </td>
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt290">
                        Y
                    </td>
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt293">
                        Y
                    </td>
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt296">
                        Y
                    </td>
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt299">
                        Y
                    </td>
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt302">
                        Y
                    </td>
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt305">
                        Y
                    </td>
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt308">
                        Y
                    </td>
                    <td class="rf-dt-c" id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt311">
                        <a onclick="availFareEnq(this,'12141','Thu Jul 03 00:00:00 IST 2014','1A','CSTM','JBP',true)">
                            1A</a> <a onclick="availFareEnq(this,'12141','Thu Jul 03 00:00:00 IST 2014','2A','CSTM','JBP',true)">
                                2A</a> <a onclick="availFareEnq(this,'12141','Thu Jul 03 00:00:00 IST 2014','3A','CSTM','JBP',true)">
                                    3A</a> <a onclick="availFareEnq(this,'12141','Thu Jul 03 00:00:00 IST 2014','SL','CSTM','JBP',true)">
                                        SL</a> <span id="ttf" style="display: none;">O,</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody id="avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:sc">
                <tr>
                    <td style="display: none">
                        <script type="text/javascript">                        new RichFaces.ui.DataTable("avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns", { "ajaxEventOptions": {} })</script>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

here i want to click on below through browser. i am not able to find below anchor: Please help me:

```
<a onclick="availFareEnq(this,'12141','Thu Jul 03 00:00:00 IST `2014','SL','CSTM','JBP',true)"> SL</a>.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could inject html into the page that is loaded in the browser control and load jquery, then inject javascript the same way that uses jquery to find the anchor tag and click it.

```
HtmlElement head = idOfBrowserControl.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];

HtmlElement script1 = idOfBrowserControl.Document.CreateElement("script");
script.SetAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script.SetAttribute("src", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js");

HtmlElement script2 = idOfBrowserControl.Document.CreateElement("script");
script.SetAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script.InnerHtml = "function clickAnchor() { $($('a', '#avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt311')[0]).click();}}";

head.AppendChild(script1);
head.AppendChild(script2);
```

Then when you want to click it, do

```
idOfBrowserControl.Document.InvokeScript("clickAnchor");
```

You don't have to inject jQuery, I just do that because I use jQuery for everything...  It's easier.

Comment: I didn't test this, I pieced it together from other questions and examples.  You might need to make changes or add more logic, but that's the basic way to do it.

Comment: hmm i getting error in script.InnerHtml = "function clickAnchor() { $('#avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt311').click();}";
 line. "Property is not supported on this type of HtmlElement."

Comment: I tried a lot. i am not able to find that anchor but it does not work.
 Plz help me.

Comment: Oh my bad, that id is the id of the table.  The anchor doesn't have an id, so I use the table, change it to

$($('a', '#avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt311')[0]).click();}

That will find the first anchor tag in table column with id avlAndFareForm:trainbtwnstns:6:j_idt311 and click it.

If you need to click a specific one, you'll have to look based on the achor tag text.  In which case you'll need to write a java script function that loops through all of the anchor tags in the table column and returns the one matching the desrired text. etc.

Comment: If you need more help, I suggest you look into JQuery and javascript tutorials.